# How to optimize a web-chat page like the image shown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to build a web-chat page like the follow image shown.
[image]

I may be select three friends to talk with, and there is a friend I current talk with. The list, which shows the chat information, can fold and unfold. And the list should pull to refresh, which means there will be many items that maybe 200 or more.

And when I switch User1 to User2, the chat information list will clear all items and add another items which show the chat information between I and User2.

Now I have achieved this, but I meet a problem: if there were too many items between I and User2, and if I switched User1 to User2, it will wait for some minutes.

So how to optimize this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your implementation.

I don't see nothing really bad with your idea, so the fact that you're suffering such a large delay suggest me that there's something wrong in your code, maybe too much overhead, maybe an incorrect way to manipulate the DOM... but as you haven't provided any code we cannot say.

The other only thing I can think that could cast this problem is that you have a truly humonguous list of elements, so big, that your client machine needs several minutes to load them. If this is the case, what you can make is just to load them partially.

Get your last 200 elements and post them into the window.

Then, on scroll event, prepare a function that retrieves other 200 elements. This way you'll only load elements into the window if your client user is asking for them.

Comment: Thank you sir, I load the elements in batches。